# How to convert PDF file Pages in to a series of Images in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I wants to convert PDF file pages  into a series of  images in wpf application .

Please help me.

Thanks & Regards

Anupam mishra

Comment: [Google search with results](https://www.google.ie/search?q=wpf+to+images&rlz=1C1PQHS_enIE547IE547&oq=wpf+to+images&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i60l2.1754j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=3fe96fe97f8ad359&q=pdf+to+images+c%23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GhostScript is a powerful tool (FREE and open source) that can convert PDF documents into image files: [Download GhostScript from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/)

This is command line tool; from .NET it can be invoked by calling Process.Start.

Comment: I used Ghostscript in combination with Imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

, worked fairly good, although I struggled a lot to get the configuration I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of libraries that can serve your purpose -

- [ABC PDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm)
- [PDF Focus .Net](http://www.sautinsoft.net/help/pdf-to-word-tiff-images-text-rtf-csharp-vb-net/index.aspx#)
- [PDF Clown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/) (Open Source)